# How can i arrange a 2-col list with CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, sorting

i'm looking for a possibility to arrange some items in a website in a 2-column list.

```
  <div class="modal-content--dropdown">
    <div class="modal-content--dropdown-header">
      <h5>HEADLINE</h5>
    </div>

    <div style="width:50%, display: inline-block;">1</div>
    <div style="width:50%, display: inline-block;">2</div>
    <div style="width:50%, display: inline-block;">3</div>
    <div style="width:50%; display: inline-block;">4</div>
    <div style="width:50%, display: inline-block;">5</div>
    <div style="width:50%, display: inline-block;">6</div>
    <div style="width:50%; display: inline-block;">7</div>
  </div>
```

if i add the items (which have 50% width and are inline), they show up in this order

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7
```

what i am trying to achieve would be to automatically sort items like this:

```
1   5
2   6
3   7
4
```

Does anybody have an approach how i could achieve this? i know how to do that by hand, but the customer should be able to add items himself without sorting it by hand, it should happen automatically. the list will in the end be rendered alphabetically.

Thanks in advance for any tip :)

Comment: You'll likely need to structure the dom differently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count):

> The `column-count` CSS property breaks an element's content into the specified number of columns.

---

example with `ol` for the demo

```css
ol {
  column-count: 2;
}

li:before {
  content: 'Item';
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-content--dropdown">
  <div class="modal-content--dropdown-header">
    <h5>HEADLINE</h5>
  </div>

  <ol>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: that looks exactly like what i needed, thanks for your input. will approve your answer asap

Comment: This evenly distributes them in the space, right? it doesn't move the overflow to the right column, it will always keep the content evenly distributed @SHRX

Comment: yes, exactly what i wanted. no matter how many items the customer adds, it will always just use as much space as needed by evenly distributing it

Comment: thanks again G-Cyr, this solution was completely unbeknownst to me and does exactly what i need. im gonna further check that attribute out as i have never seen it before and it seems quite handy. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is the most insane thing I have ever written, but I believe it matches exactly the requirements. Once an overflow occurs, it moves one item to the right and continues flowing.

```css
#list{
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#list > div{
  padding: 5px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <h5>HEADLINE</h5>
  </div>
  <div id="list">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: with 6 items, i would expect 123 on the left and 456 on the right, not 1234 left and 56 on the right

Comment: @SHRX I wrote this while still under the assumption you wanted it to be overflow based, to make that happen you would just decrease the height.

Comment: but that would mean that i have to manually set the height for the items if i add more/remove some?

Comment: Yes, for your use case, when I wrote this I didn't understand that you wanted it to be evenly distributed, so I intended for it to only overflow into the second column when the left side was exhausted

Comment: ah okay, thanks for you input and sorry for not being clear enough on this